# Switch tabs in a Chrome window without losing focus on active window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've been using a Chrome extension called Revolver Tabs for a while and now It stopped working as it should. The original developer has long discontinued supporting the extension but the code is open for everyone who would like to collaborate and so I want.

The extension switches from tab to tab in a given Chrome window as long as the extension is on. It works just fine as long as you have only 1 window set to do this. If you are using multiple windows it jumps to the tab that is being switched to as soon as the timer set runs out.

I'm new to extensions for Chrome and as far as I could explore it could have to do with the window being focused and/or given attention. Any tip?

Thanks!

Comment: It uses the deprecated `selected` property in its call to [chrome.tabs.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update). Try switching it to `highlighted` or `active`. Then reload the extension.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried both using highlighted and active but it just takes me to the tab that is being switched to.

chrome.tabs.update(nextTab.id, {active: true}) instead of .... {selected: true}

Comment: Did you ever discover a way to do this?